# mysql rename table only if it exists

Tags: mysql

I would like to rename a table only if it exist:
When I do this and the table does not exist I get an error: 
RENAME TABLE `my_table` TO `my_new_table`;

How do I write a query which does not return an error when the table does not exist?

Comment: Why don't you catch expected error?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help!

```
   IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                     AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
    BEGIN
        --Do Stuff
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this code:

```
<?php

$db = "databaseName";
$oldTable = "tableName";
$newTableName = "newTableName";
$isTableExist = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$db' AND table_name = '$oldTable'");

if($isTableExist){
    if(mysql_query("RENAME TABLE $oldTable TO $newTableName")){
        echo "Table Renamed from " . $oldTable . " to " . $newTableName . ".";
    }
    else echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Good Luck, I hope this help you. :-)